# Javascript, AJAX get MySQL content into div

Tags: mysql, ajax, html, get, swap

I would like to swap data from a MySql database with default content in one or more divs without reloading the page. I have inserted PHP code using 'set text of container' javascript behavior in Dreamweaver CS6 without success.

If anyone can tell me how to do this I would be most grateful.

Comment: Try [**Ajax**](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax).

Answer (score 0):

```
save your php code in a file named getinfo.php then call it with ajax

<?php
  include("connectdatabase.php");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $i = 1;
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Score"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In your main file use this

```
<div class="scoreBoard"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval( refreshScoreBoard, 5000 );
  var inRequest = false;
  function refreshScoreBoard() {
    if ( inRequest ) {
      return false;
    }
    inRequest = true;
    var load = $.get('getinfo.php');
    $(".scoreBoard").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log( "Error" );
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".scoreBoard").html('<table>'+res+'</table>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
      inRequest = false;
    });
  }
</script>
```